# Notepad++ crashed and reopened with all code gone

Tags: notepad++

I just spent hours working on code until Notepad++ crashed and reopened with EVERY line of code gone!!

Please tell me there is a way to recover.

Or are local web pages opened in a browser cached at all?

Comment: First google result gave this: http://superuser.com/questions/281776/does-notepad-backup-pre-edited-files-anywhere

Comment: Didn't you save the code on your hard drive?

Comment: And here is the wonder of hindsight showing us all exactly why saving work is important. Although if you were viewing code (html/javascript/php?) in a browser, presumably you were saving it as you went along?

Comment: I saved the code on my hard drive, but when Notepad++ reopened ALL the code was gone. I wasn't coding for hours and never saving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C:\Users\%your username%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup\